# Creating augmented training data by tensorflow rotation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensor

Started with `tensorflow` and `cnn` recently and I'm hoping to train a simple net to rotate features upwards.

I have a 1k dataset of images oriented upwards and using `tensorflow.contrib.image.rotate` I'd like to rotate them with random angles. 
Something within the lines of [RotNet](https://d4nst.github.io/2017/01/12/image-orientation/) but with `tensorflow` instead of `keras`.

The idea is to create `N` rotated training examples from each of the 1k images dataset. Each of the images is of 30x30x1 in shape (black and white).

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for curr in range(oriented_data.shape[0]):
        curr_image = loaded_oriented_data[curr]
        for i in range(augment_each_image):
            rotation_angle = np.random.randint(360)
            rotated_image = tfci.rotate(curr_image, np.float(rotation_angle) * math.pi/180.)
            training_data[curr + i] = sess.run(rotated_image)
            labels[curr + i] = rotation_angle
```

Now the problem is that the line `sess.run(rotated_image)` takes very long time to execute. e.g creating only 5 examples for each of the 1k has been running for over 30 mins (on cpu).
If I simply remove that line, the images get generated in a minute.

I suppose there is a way to store and work with the data as tensors instead of converting them back to ndarrays as I've been doing so far, or perhaps is there a faster function to evaluate the tensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a rotation operator for each image in `augment_each_image`, yielding a potentially very large network.

The solution is to create a *single* rotation op that you apply successively to your images. Something along those lines:

```
im_ph = tf.placeholder(...)
ang_ph = tf.placeholder(...)
rot_op = tfci.rotate(im_ph, ang_ph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for curr in range(oriented_data.shape[0]):
    curr_image = loaded_oriented_data[curr]
      for i in range(augment_each_image):
        rotation_angle = np.random.randint(360)
        rotated_image = sess.run(rot_op, {im_ph: curr_image, ang_ph: np.float(rotation_angle) * math.pi/180.})
        training_data[curr + i] = rotated_image
        labels[curr + i] = rotation_angle
```

Comment: Thank you, this runs smoothly now and I definitely learned something important!